# custom encode ascii chars between 0-31 in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding

i read some data from a device. Then i send this data to a web server via xml. The data should be represented in xml so this makes me convert characters between  0-31 because these chars can not be displayed on xml. 
The question is how can i convert the chars between 0-31 decimal in a string like `[00]abcde[01]fgh[02]...`

Are there any built-in function in .net framework or any accepted pattern?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use standard XML encoding:

```
&#12;
```

Your XML API will do that for you, so you don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: That is right.i use XmlSerializer to encode/decode xml. i have fast tested it and i see XmlSerializer does the job. It automaticly converts these chars to standart XML entity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply encode the number as an XML entity you write `&#` followed by the number and a semicolon

so 1 becomes `&#1;` and 13 becomes `&#13;` and so on and so forth

However as noted by [dan04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287586/dan04) you can't represent 0 as a numeric character reference, so in the case where your data might include 0 you will have to use a different encoding. You could encode the entire binary data as base64

Most XML toolboxes will do the encoding to NCRs for you though so you really shouldn't have to worry about that

Comment: Thank you both. That is right. See my comment on @SLaks answer.

Comment: You can't have U+0000 in an XML file, even as a numeric character reference.